# Uploading a huge file to s3 (larger than my hard drive)

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to an S3 bucket, but the problem is that the file I want to upload (and also create) is bigger than what my hard drive can hold (I want to store a 500TB file on the bucket)

Is there any way to do so?
The file is generated, so I thought about generating the file as I go while it uploads, but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks in advace

Comment: max file size is 5TB in S3.

Answer (score 0):

The [Multipart Upload API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) allows you to upload a file in chunks, including on-the-fly content generation... but the maximum size of an object in S3 is 5 TiB.

Also, it costs a minimum of $11,500 to store 500 TiB in S3 for 1 month, not to mention the amount of time it takes to upload it... but if this is a justifiable use case, you might consider using some [Snowball Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball-edge/faqs/) devices, each of which has its own built-in 100 TiB of storage.